# R: creating xts changes dataset, losing data

Tags: r, xts, posixct

when creating an `xts`object from a `data.frame` I seem to lose some data (approximately 3000 data lost over 33 000).

My dataset is as follow: (with the time being day-month-year, EU format)

```
> head(mesdonnees)
              time value
1 05-03-2006 04:07    NA
2 05-03-2006 04:17    NA
3 05-03-2006 04:27    NA
4 05-03-2006 04:37    NA
5 05-03-2006 04:47    NA
6 05-03-2006 04:57    NA
```

Due to the format I had to extract the different parts of the date (at least I couldn't get `as.POSIXct` to work with this format).
Here is how I did it:

```
# Extract characters and define as S....
Syear <- substr(mesdonnees$time, 7,10)
Smonth <- substr(mesdonnees$time, 4,5)
Sday <- substr(mesdonnees$time, 1, 2)

#Gather all parts and use "-" as sep
datetext <- paste(Syear, Smonth, Sday, sep="-")
#define format of each part of the string
formatdate<-as.POSIXct(datetext, format="%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT")
```

I then try to create my `xts`with...

```
xtsdata <- xts(mesdonnees$value, order.by = formatdate, tz = "GMT")
```

... but when doing this I get some quite weird results: the first value is in 1900

```
> head(xtsdata)
           [,1]
1900-01-04   NA
2006-03-05   NA
2006-03-05   NA
2006-03-05   NA
2006-03-05   NA
2006-03-05   NA
```

and many (3000) dates are not kept:

```
> xtsdata[30225:30233,]
           [,1]
2006-12-31    0
2006-12-31    0
2006-12-31    0
2006-12-31    0
<NA>         NA
<NA>         NA
<NA>         NA
<NA>         NA
<NA>         NA
```

When looking at what should be the same line in both my `data.frame`and my `xts`I can see that the lines are offset (I had the date format changed in the `xts` object creation):

```
> mesdonnees[25617,]
                  time value
25617 08-11-2006 23:51     0
> xtsdata[25617,]
           [,1]
2006-11-25 0.27
```

How is it that my data are offset? I tried changing the `tz` but it doesn't affect it. I removed all duplicates using the `dyplr package`, it doesn't affect the xts results either. Thank you for your help !

---

After changing my `xts` code to the one suggested by Joshua:

```
xtsdata <- xts(mesdonnees$value, order.by = as.POSIXct(mesdonnees$time, tz = "GMT", format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
```

... my data show properly for the "last" part, but I now have a different problem. The first 2300 data show the following results when doing (using `xtsdata[1500,]` (or any row < 2300) displays the same results)

```
> view(xtsdata):
0206-06-30 23:08:00    NA
0206-06-30 23:18:00    NA
0206-06-30 23:28:00    NA
1900-01-04 12:00:00    NA
2006-03-05 04:07:00    NA
2006-03-05 04:17:00    NA
```

I noticed this error before and thought it was due to the date format; maybe it is not? Also, when looking at the `xtsdata` I do not get the same results for the same row (the last rows are correct thought):

```
> mesdonnees[2360,]
                 time value
2360 23-03-2006 03:09    NA
> xtsdata[2360,]
                    [,1]
2006-03-05 09:07:00   NA
```

As requested:

```
> str(mesdonnees)
'data.frame':   32556 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time : chr  "05-03-2006 04:07" "05-03-2006 04:17" "05-03-2006 04:27" "05-03-2006 04:37" ...
 $ value: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

And if needed:

```
An ‘xts’ object on 0206-06-01 00:09:00/2006-12-31 23:29:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:32556, 1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: GMT
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Comment: Please edit the output of `str(mesdonnees)` into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only include the date portion of the timestamp in `datetext` and `formatdate`, but your data have dates and times.

You also do not need to do all the string subsetting. You can achive the same result by specifying the `format` argument in your `as.POSIXct` call.

```
xtsdata <- xts(mesdonnees$value,
               as.POSIXct(mesdonnees$times, "GMT", format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Hello, your solution worked for the "last" part of my data (which were not converted into dates).
But it still doesn't work for the beginning of the data set (I will edit the post with more details)

Comment: The problem is that your datetimes are in two (or more?) different formats.  You should replace the `as.POSIXct` call with `anytime::anytime` or `lubridate::ymdhms`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that the initial dataset had some messed up date format; the year is written wrong ("206" instead of "2006").
Thank you for pointing it out, case is solved.